# $('html').click event after another click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Intention:

1. On click of (#clickme) a DIV slides down and comes into view and (var isclicked = true)
2. When (var isclicked = true) and on click of (#clickme), DIV slides up and (var isclicked = false)
3. While (var isclicked = true) and DIV is in view, on click of $('html') slides the DIV up and (var isclicked = false)

Issue:
While DIV is in the slideDown position, (var isclicked = true), on click of $('html') keeps firing.  What am I missing so that on click o f $('html') only fires WHILE DIV is (var isclicked = true)

```
var isclicked = false; 
$('#clickme').click(function(event){
  doslider();       
  console.log(isclicked);    
  if(isclicked == true){
     $('html').click(function(event){
         console.log('is box opened? '+isclicked);
     });        
  } 
});


function doslider(){     
 if(isclicked == false){    
     $('#myslider').slideDown('slow');         
       isclicked = true;                
 }else{
     $('#myslider').slideUp('slow');
       isclicked = false;          
 }   
 return isclicked; }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Zfwx/92/

Comment: what do you mean by "only fires WHILE DIV is (var isclicked = true)"?

Comment: see my answer do you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the global `isClicked` var, and just use a `slideToggle`:

```
$("#clickme").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#myslider").slideToggle("slow");
});

$("body").click(function() {
    $("#myslider").is(":visible") ? $("#myslider").slideUp("slow") : 0
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Zfwx/103/

Comment: This works.   e.stopPropagation(); and  $("#myslider").is(":visible") does the trick.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remember to stop (and complete) the previous animation first:

```
if(isclicked == false){    
    $('#myslider').stop(true, true).slideDown('slow');
      isclicked = true;       
}else{
    $('#myslider').stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
      isclicked = false;   
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/7Zfwx/94/

Answer (score 0):

use `$('body')` instead of `$('html')`

[see this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Zfwx/109/)